# Python logging with Config file working with only 1 file

Tags: python, logging, configuration

Am new to python and trying to understand logging (am not new to programming at all though). Trying to replicate log4j logger that we have in Java. Have a simple test project of the following files:
- User.py
- Test.py
- conf/
      - logging.conf
- log

All the python files have logger objects to log to specific file mentioned in logging.conf. However, only the Test.py file dumps logs. Not the User.py file.

User.py is as follows:

```py
    import logging
    import logging.config

    logging.config.fileConfig('conf/logging.conf')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    class User:
        username = ""
        password = ""
        def __init__(self, username = "username", password = "password"):
            global logger
            logger.debug( "In User constructor" );
            self.username = username
            self.password = password
            logger.debug( "Out User constructor" );

        def getSomething(self) :
            return "Something"

        def login_user(self) :
            logger.debug( "In login_user" );
            logger.debug( "Out login_user" );
            return "Logged In"
```

Test.py as follows:

```py
    from User import User
    import logging
    import logging.config
    from threading import Thread

    logging.config.fileConfig('conf/logging.conf')
    logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)

    objectsCount = 1
    logger.debug("In VolumeTest")

    def thr_func(username, password):
        logger.info("In thr_func")
        user1 = User(username, password)
        logger.info("Created user obj")
        logger.info("Before login_user call")
        token = user1.login_user()
        logger.debug ( "Out thr_func")

    def main() :    
        thr_func( "abc", "def" )

        logger.info("In Main")
        thr_objects = []
        for i in range(objectsCount):
            thread = Thread(target=thr_func, args=("subhayan", "MER2018"))
            thr_objects.append(thread)

        logger.info("Main    : before running thread")

        for i in range(objectsCount):
            logger.info("Main    : starting thread " + str(i))
            thr_objects[i].start()
            logger.info("Main    : started thread " + str(i))

        logger.info("Main    : wait for the thread to finish")

        for i in range(objectsCount):
        thr_objects[i].join()
    logger.info("Main    : all done")    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

logging.conf file as follows:

```py
    [loggers]
    keys=root

    [handlers]
    keys=logfile

    [formatters]
    keys=logfileformatter

    [logger_root]
    level=DEBUG
    handlers=logfile

    [formatter_logfileformatter]
    format=%(asctime)s %(name)-12s: %(threadName)s : %(levelname)s : %(message)s

    [handler_logfile]
    #class=handlers.RotatingFileHandler
    class=handlers.TimedRotatingFileHandler
    #class=TimedCompressedRotatingFileHandler
    level=DEBUG
    #args=('testing.log','a',10,100)
    args=('log/testing.log','d', 1, 9, None, False, False)
    formatter=logfileformatter
```

I tried running using : "python Test.py". However, no logs from User file So, the question is, can't we have logging for the second file in this way ? What am I doing wrong ? If nothing wrong, what is the best way to do this in python ?

Answer (score 2):

I see a couple of things that may be the issue:
1) you're running 2 separate loggers: each file is instantiating it's own logger pointed to the same file. 
2) if you want everything in the same file, then create one logger and pass the reference to other modules via a global var. I find it easier to create a log.py file that creates and writes the log file, and then import that module into the other modules.
2) you have a file handler and a formatter in your config file, but don't seem to set it in the code. Something like

```
handler = logging.handlers.RotatingFileHandler(LOG_FILENAME, ...
f = logging.Formatter('%(process)d %(asctime)s %(levelname)s: %(message)s')
handler.setFormatter(f)
logger.addHandler(handler)
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks tbitson for the pointers. Here is the changed code.

```
import logging
import logging.config

logging.config.fileConfig('conf/logging.conf')
logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
```

The modified User.py is:

```
from logger import logger

class User:
    username = ""
    password = ""
    def __init__(self, username = "username", password = "password"):
        global logger
        logger.debug( "In User constructor" );
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        logger.debug( "Out User constructor" );

    def getSomething(self) :
        return "Something"

    def login_user(self) :
        logger.debug( "In login_user" );
        logger.debug( "Out login_user" );
        return "Logged In"
```

The modified Test.py is:
    from User import User
    from logger import logger 
    from threading import Thread

```
objectsCount = 1
logger.debug("In VolumeTest")

def thr_func(username, password):
    logger.info("In thr_func")
    user1 = User(username, password)
    logger.info("Created user obj")
    logger.info("Before login_user call")
    token = user1.login_user()
    logger.debug ( "Out thr_func")

def main() :    
    thr_func( "abc", "def" )

    logger.info("In Main")
    thr_objects = []
    for i in range(objectsCount):
        thread = Thread(target=thr_func, args=("subhayan", "MER2018"))
        thr_objects.append(thread)

    logger.info("Main    : before running thread")

    for i in range(objectsCount):
        logger.info("Main    : starting thread " + str(i))
        thr_objects[i].start()
        logger.info("Main    : started thread " + str(i))

    logger.info("Main    : wait for the thread to finish")

    for i in range(objectsCount):
        thr_objects[i].join()
    logger.info("Main    : all done")    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```